# VS code перестал отличать типы данных python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Пример:

```
def great_user(username):
    """выводит приветствие"""
    print(f"Hello, {str(username).title()}!")


great_user(input("What is your name? "))
```

В третьей строке вместо того, чтобы написать username.title() приходится писать так, как написано выше. VS code видит в этом ошибку. Также и со словарями, при переборе ключей и значений через .items() нужно намеренно указывать, что это строковый тип данных

У кого было также, либо если кто-то знает как решить, то буду очень благодарен.

P.S Если как-то поможет делу, то я пару дней назад откатился с 3.12 из-за проблем с совместимостью пакетов

Comment: А почему вы решили, что username это строка? А вдруг `great_user(4)` или `great_user([])`?

Comment: andreymal, запрос идёт через обычный input. Если бы я писал там int(input()) или float(input()) тогда бы ещё можно было понять, но тут стандартный тип без уточнений всегда str

Comment: И всё-таки а вдруг `great_user(4)` или `great_user([])` — никто в общем случае не знает, кто когда и с какими параметрами будет вызывать эту функцию, и ваш инпут это всего лишь один из частных случаев

Comment: Тоже имеет место быть. Я бы так не спорил, если бы точно такой же кусок кода не работал по другому буквально позавчера, поэтому пока списываю на баг

Comment: Ладно, «VS code видит в этом ошибку» — какую именно ошибку?

Comment: Сказав, что это ошибка, скорее всего я загнул. По факту там нет подсветки синтаксиса и не вылазит список доступных методов

Comment: Потому что VS Code не знает что такое username, это может быть что угодно

Comment: Хорошо, но мне не даёт покоя то, что до этого VS Code спокойно переваривал такое, а после отката пошли такие прелести

Comment: Не знаю как он мог такое переваривать. Для начала напишите хотя бы `def great_user(username: str) -> None:` чтобы VS Code знал что это вообще такое